# How can I turn an xml Element into an ElementTree (python)?

Tags: python, xml

As I understood it, XML files are tree structures ie each branch is its own tree. Conceptually, I can't see the difference between an Element and an ElementTree. But I guess that's ok - what's worse is that there is stuff you can't do with an Element - for example `root.write("bla.xml")` seems to be fine but `element.write("bla.xml")` doesn't work.

So I suppose I need to convert the Element to an ElementTree and set it as root before I do anything else. How do I do this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, conceptually there is no difference. So, just build you elements however you like, and then just include their root in an ElementTree so you have access its methods. You can just do

```
tree = ElementTree(my_root_element)
tree.write(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the root tree from an xml Element, you can use the getroottree method:

```
doc = lxml.html.parse(s)
tree = doc.getroottree()
```

> for more info please check the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to know more about the module.